# VB.Net chart point label not displaying

Tags: vb.net, charts, label

I'm trying to add a label to a point in VB.Net using the Chart control. Here's my code:

```
                chartMain.Series(1).Points.AddXY(x, y)
                chartMain.Series(1).Points(chartMain.Series(1).Points.Count - 1).Label = Math.Round(x, 2) & "nm, " & Math.Round(y, 2) & "%"
```

However no labels are being displayed. In another program I do this exact same thing and it works perfectly. Is there something I'm missing or may have inadvertently disabled elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed -

Data point type of "Fast Point" will not display labels, it seems. Changing to just "Point" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ChartMain.Series(1).Points.AddXY(Math.Round(x, 2) & "nm, " & Math.Round(y, 2) & "%", y)
```

Comment: Doing this does not work, as I am adding this point as an overlay to a chart where there is an existing plot. I need the point to be plotted correctly, not just added to the end.